# Cómo evitar el uso de "Dynamic" en una función génerica que retorna el valor de un tipo variable?

Tags: c#, template, genericos

Estoy haciendo una clase génerica y me acabo de ver en una tesitura.
En príncipio la clase iba a ser así:

```
public class EventInfo<T>
{
    public T tipo;

    public EventInfo(T pTipo)
    {
        tipo=pTipo;
    }

    public object GetData()
    {
        if (tipo is IDamage)
        {
            var d = tipo as IDamage;
            return d.Data;//-->retorna un "int"
        }
        else if (tipo is IWeapon)
        {
            var d = tipo as IWeapon;
            return d.Data;//-->retorna un "string"
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Pero luego he pensado que podría ser mas práctico si pudiera hacer que la función "GetData()" fuese todavia aún mas genérica ya que tengo pensado ir añadiendo mas interfaces (mas tipos a comparar).

Pero lo único que se me ha ocurrido es hacerlo así (usando dynamic):

```
public class EventInfo<T>
{
    public T tipo;

    public EventInfo(T pTipo)
    {
        tipo=pTipo;
    }

    public object GetData<D>() where D : class
    {
        if (tipo is D)
        {
            dynamic d = tipo as D;
            return d.Data;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

La cuestión es que no me gusta usar `dynamic` porque el compilador no te da ningún mensaje de error en caso de que cometas alguna equivocación.

¿Alguien sabe alguna forma de hacer exactamente lo mismo pero sin usar dynamic?
Muchas Gracias!!

```
//------------------------------------------------
//Acutualizacion (añadiendo mas código por si 
//alguien quiere tener una visión mas amplia del lo que quiero hacer)
//------------------------------------------------


    //-------------------------------------------------- 
    public interface IData<T>
    {
        T Data { set; get; }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------- 
    public class CData<T> : IData<T>
    {
        private T data;
        public T Data
        {
            set { data = value; }
            get { return data; }
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------- 
    public interface IDamage : IData<int> { }
    public interface IHealth : IData<int> { }
    public interface IWeapon : IData<string> { }
    public interface IScore  : IData<int> { }
   //--------------------------------------------------
    public class Damage : CData<int>, IDamage
    {
        public Damage(int pData)
        {
            Data = pData;
        }
    }
    //-------------------------------------------------- 
    public class Weapon : CData<string>, IWeapon
    {
        public Weapon(string pData)
        {
            Data = pData;
        }
    }
    //--------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: no termino de entender.. si ya sabes el tipo que tiene la clase, entonces para que hacer el if? porque no retornar directamente d.Data? ademas que sabiendo el tipo no sirve de nada, porque siempre devolves un objet y siempre es d.Data....

Comment: Lo voy a enviar como parametro en un Action<EventInfo<T>> (un evento) el que lo recibe solo sabe el tipo que necesita "D" es decir la interfaz que necesita.... pero quiero que la funcion sea generica para poder enviar cualquier tipo de dato con la misma función... si no tendría que hacer una diferente para cada interfaz... o hacerlo como en el ejemplo de la primera clase... o al menos esa es la idea...

Comment: Pensadolo bien... creo que tienes razón... aun así usar dynamic no me da buena espina..... pero si no lo pongo me da errores... :-(

Comment: igual ese dynamic ahi pasa a ser object, con lo cual es lo mismo... sigue siendo algo indefinido... yo no termino de comprender tu contexto entero...

Comment: Espera que añado mas código ahí arriba y asi a lo mejor lo ves mejor...

Comment: Tenia todos los datos en una sola interfaz y los enviaba todos juntos en los eventos... pero me está dando problemas cuando tengo mas de dos scripts en el mismo objeto que envien eventos e implementen la misma interfaz... por eso he pensado en separar todos los datos y que cada uno evie sus propio datos... (Problemas de Unity)

Answer (score 0):

Parece que lo he conseguido... **plantillas + poliformismo!!**
Dejo la respuesta aquí por si a alguien le sirve de ayuda...
De todas formas si alguien me da una solución mejor que esta se la eceptaré con mucho gusto.

```
//-------------------------------------------------- 

using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public interface IData<T>
{
    T Data { set; get; }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class CData<T> : IData<T>
{
    private T data;
    public T Data
    {
        set { data = value; }
        get { return data; }
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public interface IDamage : IData<int> { }

//-------------------------------------------------- 

public class Damage : CData<int>, IDamage
{
    public Damage(int pData)
    {
        Data = pData;
    }
}

//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class EventInfo<T> where T : class
{
    public T tipo;

    public EventInfo(T pTipo)
    {
        tipo=pTipo;
    }     


    public X GetData<X, D>() where D : class
    {
        if (tipo is D)
        {
            var d = tipo as IData<X>;
            return d.Data;
        }
        return default(X);
    }

}

//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class Event<T>
{
    public Action<T> handler;
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class Listener
{    
    public void DamageHandler(EventInfo<IDamage> f)
    {
        Console.Write("\n result=" + f.GetData<int, IDamage>());
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
public class EntryPoint
{
    static void Main()
    {
        IDamage d = new Damage(10);
        EventInfo<IDamage> f = new EventInfo<IDamage>(d);

        Event<EventInfo<IDamage>> et = new Event<EventInfo<IDamage>>();
        et.handler += l.DamageHandler;
        et.handler.Invoke(f);
    }
}
//-------------------------------------------------- 
//C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\csc.exe Poliformismo.cs
//--------------------------------------------------
```